# RuntimeException vendor does not exist and could not be created

Tags: php, json, vagrant, composer-php

I've tried other posts I found online but none seemed to work correctly. I'm working with [this](http://www.dev-metal.com/install-php-login-nets-4-full-mvc-framework-login-script-ubuntu/). And I make my way to the root of it, which is `/var/www/`. So then I do `composer install` and I have a `composer.json` file in there. I get

```
[RuntimeException]                               
vendor does not exist and could not be created.
```

Here's the file

```
{
    "name": "panique/php-login",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "A PHP login system embedded in a simple MVC framework",
    "keywords": ["login", "auth", "user", "authentification", "mvc"],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/panique/php-login",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Panique",
            "homepage": "http://careers.stackoverflow.com/panique",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/panique/php-login/issues",
        "source": "https://github.com/panique/php-login"
    },
    "require":{
        "php": ">=5.3.7",
        "ircmaxell/password-compat": "1.0.*",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "5.2.*",
        "gregwar/captcha": "dev-master",
        "facebook/php-sdk": "@stable",
        "raveren/kint": "dev-1.0.0-wip"
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here....

Answer (score 140):

Googlers, do not use composer with sudo:

Add your user in the www-data group (this action require you to logout and login again)

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data `whoami`
```

Give the right permissions to /var/www

```
sudo chown root:root /var/www
sudo chmod 755 /var/www/
```

Give these permissions to your project

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/<project>
sudo chmod -R 774 /var/www/<project>
```

Comment: Reasons this question is correct: a) You're allowing third party scripts to execute as ROOT... big security risk! b) you're ssh key will no longer be available (cant pull from github/bitbucket) c) you will be forever chowning things back to `www-data` or `username` (like `/home/user/.composer` file)

Comment: When I add these permissions from host machine, I get this error: `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/var/www/project\") set in config.json failed: permission denied": unknown` Any idea why I am getting this?

Comment: Run `sudo chown root:root /var/www`, I get `chown: cannot access '/var/www': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 39):

@Etienne Gautier's solution will certainly work.

Another solution is just to change the permissions of the user/group of `/vendor`.

e.g.

```
sudo chmod -R 775  /ROOT_OF_YOUR_APP/vendor/
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /ROOT_OF_YOUR_APP/vendor/
```

Comment: Verry usefull answer but before doing this first creat a vendor folder in your project folder

Answer (score 23):

if you are a linux user, run the following command

```
sudo chown -R user projectFolder/
```

then run composer install. user is the username of your machine. If you are not sure just run

```
whoami
```

from the terminal

Comment: `sudo chown -R $(whoami) projectFolder/` shortcut for lazy people like me :)

Answer (score 8):

I was able to solve this type of issue by removing the vendor folder and then re-installing using `composer update`. Hope this helps someone like me.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue with updating my package. The reason why it did not work for me is that this folder 'to be created' already existed and had to be deleted before this composer update could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Manually create vendor folder inside of your laravel app *sudo mkdir vendor* and give 777 permission to it *sudo chmod 777 vendor/* and then go back to your app location and run composer update.

Then, again bootstrap/cache permission may occur give 777 permission recursively to cache folder *sudo chmod -R 777 cache/* then go back to your app location and run composer update.

Make sure you have setup your .env file in your laravel app.

Then you are good to go:)

Answer (score 1):

Run this command `sudo composer install`[image]

its work in my case hopefully helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me, seems like a permission issue, you got two choices:

1. Give you user permissions like mentioned in `Etienne Gautier's` answer above or
2. Log in with your root user

Answer (score -3):

This happens because we do not have administrator permissions, we just have to put the word sudo, it would look like this: sudo composer install

Comment: How many times must it be said that composer must **not** be run as root?

Comment: if this is on your local there is no real issue running composer with sudo