# Laravel 5 issue : libraries/admin/ does not exist and could not be created

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I'm trying to install laravel from git. I cloned the repository and tried the command

```
php artisan serve
```

But It gave this error message.

> Warning:
>   require(C:\wamp64\www\reguard\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\reguard\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\wamp64\www\reguard\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\wamp64\www\reguard\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

and I ran a **composer install**

But it stopped with this error,

> [RuntimeException]   libraries/admin/ does not exist and could not be
>   created.

So I ran a **composer du** as the first comment but now getting this,

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]   Class
>   'R2S\Admin\Providers\AdminServiceProvider' not found

Hope someone can help.

Comment: run`composer du`

Comment: Thanks I did but still another issue coming sorry

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeException vendor does not exist and could not be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390001/runtimeexception-vendor-does-not-exist-and-could-not-be-created)