# How to get my composer working with Drupal 8

Tags: composer-php, drupal-8, runtimeexception, drush

After a lot of effort I finally managed to get my composer (with drush) working with Drupal 8.5.3
However I would like to update Drupal to latest version with composer.

Updating composer with sudo doesnt gives me errors but doesnt update my Drupal.

I used this command from my project dir;

```
sudo composer update drush/drush --with-dependencies
```

I read that it's bad practice to use sudo for composer and because it doesnt update my Drupal

I try using composer update without sudo.
First I got some warnings that cache could not be used. Because they're only warnings I ignored them.

After some time it sees 11 updates and right after that I got a big red errormessage;

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 11 updates, 0 removals


  [RuntimeException]
  /path-to-my-site/drupal-composer-build/vendor/symfony/polyfill-ctype does not exist and could not be created.
```

I then tried the sollution in [RuntimeException] vendor does not exist and could not be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390001/runtimeexception-vendor-does-not-exist-and-could-not-be-created/43513522#43513522)

So I did;

*Add your user in the www-data group (this action require you to logout and login again)*

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data `whoami`
```

*Give these permissions to your project*

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/<project>
sudo chmod -R 774 /var/www/<project>
```

I skipped the 2nd part that gives rights to /var/www because I'm on a shared server without root userrights.

I got the following message;

```
No composer.json in current directory, do you want to use the one at /path-to-site? [Y,n]? y
```

after that got some cache warnings again and the following question;

```
Cannot create cache directory /home/maikel/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/maikel/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/maikel/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 6 updates, 0 removals
- Updating symfony/event-dispatcher (v3.4.14 => v3.4.15):
 Update failed (Could not delete /path-to-site/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/GenericEvent.php: )
Would you like to try reinstalling the package instead [yes]? y
```

I anwered yes again, then;

```
- Removing symfony/event-dispatcher (v3.4.14)
[RuntimeException]
Could not delete /path-to-site/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/GenericEvent.php:

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] 
[--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-
progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] 
[-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-
authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-
stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] 
[<packages>]...
```

My two questions are;

- Do I really really need composer (with drush)? I rather drop composer
  or Drupal alltogether
- If I really need it to properly manage updates in the future, how can
  I configure composer to update, do I need a global configuration?

Thanks a lot in advance
If I can update this question with more information/config files please let me know, I'll gladly do, I honestly don't know where to begin.

Comment: Start with delete `vendor` (in your project) and `home/maikel/.composer` directories and then try run `composer install` as not root.

Comment: Thanks @rob006, I'll try tomorrow morning and let you know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RuntimeException\] vendor does not exist and could not be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390001/runtimeexception-vendor-does-not-exist-and-could-not-be-created)