# create Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, installation

Please help me! I installed composer and then I create Laravel project via command:

```
composer create-project Laravel/Laravel myapp
```

but it show error message:

> [RuntimeException]
> php: does not exist and could not be created

How to solve?

Here my full command prompt:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs>composer create-project laravel/laravel cms
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./cms"
Installing laravel/laravel (v8.5.22)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v8.5.22): Extracting archive


  [RuntimeException]
  php: does not exist and could not be created.


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

Comment: Please add your error image or describe the full error so got it proper solution.

Comment: Please check your `composer` install properly and what is your exact error?

Comment: It may be a permission issue .Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390001/runtimeexception-vendor-does-not-exist-and-could-not-be-created

Comment: PHP is in your PATH ? You can try the EasyPHP module "Laravel & Laravel Manager" (https://warehouse.easyphp.org/inventory-devserver#applications)

Comment: It not solve yet.

Comment: what is the output of `php -v`?

Comment: `composer self-update` to get latest version and it should work. If you do a fresh install, don't ever download Composer from anywhere other than https://getcomposer.org/

Answer (score -2):

try installing old composer version, maybe this version has problem.

here is the link for the 2.1.5 version.

https://www.malavida.com/en/soft/composer/