# Failed to download symfony/skeleton from dist: /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/composer does not exist and could not be created

Tags: php, symfony

Problem with Composer. I can not find solution on the Stack.

Im new with Symfony, so i have tried to make a new project with this command:composer create-project symfony/skeleton my_project_directory.

I get this result: Failed to download symfony/skeleton from dist: /opt/lampp/htdocs/vendor/composer does not exist and could not be created.
Now trying to download from source

- Syncing symfony/skeleton (v6.2.99) into cache
- Installing symfony/skeleton (v6.2.99): Cloning 3f1275f599 from cache
  Install of symfony/skeleton failed

In Filesystem.php line 314:

Could not delete /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_project_directory.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeException vendor does not exist and could not be created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390001/runtimeexception-vendor-does-not-exist-and-could-not-be-created)

Answer (score 0):

If "/opt/lampp/htdocs/" is general folder of your projects, u need to set access rights to:

```
chmod g+s /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

Now, u need to delete already created "my_project_directory" folder:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/lampp/htdocs/my_project_directory
```

Then create new one with composer command:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"6.2.*" my_project_directory
```